# Error 500 when sending 'POST' request with basic authentication in node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to hit API in POST Method with basic authentication in node js but getting error `response.statusCode: 500`

i tried several code and hints for this but not able to get the proper output.
in this post method i have to send some data as well.

```
    username = "user",
        password = "test@1453",

        auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
        var headers = {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN':'aaaaaa-bbbbbb-1235-ws12-23232jfnfh45',
         'Content-Type':'application/json',
         "Authorization" : auth
     }
var body = {
                   "flowUuid":"ws123-sed34-2345-ff45-d3f5drfvd331a",
                    "logLevel": "EXTENDED",
                    "inputs":
                             {
                             "SourceMachine":"10.20.30.40",
                             "DestinationIP":"abc.domain.com"
                             }
                   }

             url= 'https://xxx-xxxx-aa.domian.com:8443/aa/rest/v2/executions/',

             request({
                        url: url,
                        body: body,
                        json: true,
                        method:'POST',
                        headers: headers,
                        rejectUnauthorized: false,

                    }, function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                            console.log(body)
                        }
                        else {

                            console.log("error: " + error)
                            console.log("response.statusCode: " + response.statusCode)
                            console.log("response.statusText: " + response.statusText)
                        }
                    })
```

Please help in this.

Comment: But other API endpoints is working just as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can hit the api with POST method in angular services passing 3 parameters
1) api URL
2) data that you want to pass
3) headers

The header contains your authentication token, through which api will come to know that a user is valid or not. This authentication token you get after you successfully login and you will have to store it in localStorage.

Please refer the below code

```
callToApiPost(body):Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('your_token')
        })
    }

    return this.http.post('https://xxx-xxxx-aa.domian.com:8443/aa/rest/v2/executions/', body, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap((res:any) => {
            console.log('got the result, api call was successfull');
        }),
        catchError(console.log('error while calling api'))
    )
}
```